# postgres jdbc insert array of custom type

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, orm

I want to insert array of custom type into `postgres` with `jdbc`.

my sql schema:

```
CREATE TYPE element_pk_t AS (
    workspace_id   BIGINT,
    element_id     BIGINT,
    history_id     BIGINT
);
```

my java class:

```
public class ElementPK {
    public Long workspaceId;

    public Long elementId;

    public Long historyId;
}
```

How should I do this in `java` with `jdbc`?

I've found tutorial regarding custom type https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlcustommapping.html, but array of custom type is still unclear to me.

One trivial approach is using pure string style SQL statement, but I still prefer using `PreparedStatement` with `setObject` or `setArray`

Comment: Loop through the array and insert each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then, from the Java code, you need to generate query that looks, for example, like this:

```
INSERT INTO parent_table(elements) 
VALUES (
ARRAY[
     row(1, 2, 3)::element_pk, 
     row(4, 5, 6)::element_pk, 
     row(7, 8, 9)::element_pk
]);
```

Assuming that you have a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NOW(),
    elements element_pk[]
)
```

And the Type like you described. If I were you, I wont implement it via an array. I would have use JSONB instead - in this way you wont lose an ability to use indexing. Of course, there is `java.sql.Array` out there, and you can still do it via the following:

```
Array array = connection.createArrayOf("public.element_pk", new ElementPK[]{
                new ElementPK(1, 2, 3),
                new ElementPK(9, 4, 6)
        });
```

And then set the array, to `PgPreparedStatement`, but the thing is that internally PgPreparedStatement will enclose your elements within curly braces, which is ok, but each element will be represented by its toString method call result. I mean, assume your ElementPK toString looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "This is how it is implemented, really?";
    }
```

then you will get the SQL like:

```
INSERT INTO parent_table (elements) VALUES ('{"This is how it is implemented, really?","This is how it is implemented, really?"}')
```

Again, it is *maybe* possible to adopt it, but from my perspective - at least having your logic within toString method is not that great, is it? **Spare yourself and do the following:**

```
CREATE TABLE via_jsonb(
    elements JSONB
);
```

and then simply:

```
INSERT INTO via_jsonb VALUES(
'{
    "workspace_id" : 1,
    "element_id" : 2,
    "history_id" : 3
 }'
);
```

and in the Java code I would have simply create json from your object and set it as a string. Really, there are [a lot of functions and cool features](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) on JSONB out of the box.

Hope it helped, have a nice day!)

Comment: Thanks! really helpful answer. Yeah the `toString()` approach is just too adhoc, totally agree, I'll consider using jsonb

Answer (score 1):

Follow up to the last part of @misha2045 answer.

If you still refuese to use JSONB for whatever reason you need to add parenthesis at the end and start of your toString method.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "("+this.field1+ ", " + this.field2+")";
}
```

Then set the array in the prepared statement

```
ps.setArray(1, con.createArrayOf("yourType", yourClassArray));
```